# How to check if value service is already defined angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to develop modular services in angularjs which can be used in other project just with including in the root (like angularjs, jquery...). For example I have anonymous function like:

```
(function(ng, app) {
    'use strict';

    app.value('SomeValue', function(param1, param2) {
        //code here
    }

})(angular, app);
```

What I need is to check if this value (service) is already defined in the angularjs app and throw error if it is. I was searching over net for hours and also in Angularjs documentation, and in the $provide section it just says how to register. I tried with this,

```
$provide('SomeValue')
```

or

```
var checkForValue = function($provide){ //to inject the provide service
   //and here is undefined
}
```

or

```
app.value('SomeValue'); //to see if this return something
```

with not luck at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inject `$injector` to your service and call:

```
$injector.has('SomeValue')
```